# Weird SwiftUI ColorPicker problem (XCode 13.4.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

This is a completely trivial view, but I cannot get it to work. I am targeting iOS 15.5.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var bgColor = Color.red

    var body: some View {
            ColorPicker("Set the background color", selection: $bgColor)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(bgColor)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Pressing the button, the view dims slightly, but the expected color picking view does not show, and then I get these errors in the console (some of them appear repeatedly):

```
*2022-08-11 23:17:38.322396-0400 PickColors[9817:2995923] [lifecycle] [u 637E7E44-8DD2-4D64-AE35-AB59C96C5CED:m (null)] [com.apple.UIKit.ColorPicker(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.*

*2022-08-11 23:17:38.324038-0400 PickColors[9817:2995917] [lifecycle] [u 637E7E44-8DD2-4D64-AE35-AB59C96C5CED:m (null)] [com.apple.UIKit.ColorPicker(1.0)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.*

2022-08-11 23:17:38.874934-0400 PickColors[9817:2995917] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>

*2022-08-11 23:17:40.141197-0400 PickColors[9817:2995917] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>*
```

I don't know what to make of the errors. I've tried all sorts of voodoo, like putting the color picker inside a stack (H, V or Z, no difference) or a NavigationView, as well as the usual hocus pocus: cleaning the build folder and restarting Xcode. No joy. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for info, all works well for me, although I am on Xcode 14.0

Comment: Copied code and everything works for me. Check out your build settings and consider restarting your machine.

Comment: Restarting did not help, either.

Comment: What build settings could be affecting this? I'm starting with a fresh project, with all defaults.

Comment: Hmm. Works perfectly on 14.0 beta 5, so maybe there is something wrong with my installation of 13.4.1. I'll report back after reinstalling.

Comment: Working here too. There may be another different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. It was a corrupted 13.4.1. A reinstall cured the problem.